# What's the point of using wordy Time Zones?

Tags: php, timezone

I know this isn't specific to PHP, but what's the point of using timezones listed like this :https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php?  For example "America/Indianapolis" and  "America/New_York".  What is the problem with EST, EDT, CST, CDT, &c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a [different timezone format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) provided by the [Zoneinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo):

> The time zones in the database are
>   given uniform names, such as
>   “America/New_York”, in an attempt to
>   make them easier to understand by
>   humans and to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 11):

`'America/New_York'` doesn't depend on the date. `EST` is only valid in winter, while in summer you have to change it to `EDT`. Other problem with 3 letter codes is, that there are conflicts. `EST` means Eastern Standard Time, but it might be in America or Australia.

Comment: I believe in the US it's <b>Eastern</b> Standard Time (EST), and in Australia it's Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST).  It is likely, however, that there are other abbreviation collisions.

Comment: «Central Summer Time (CST) or Central Daylight Time (CDT), possibly with "Australia" prefixed (ACST or ACDT). The time in the southeastern states become UTC+11, using "Eastern" in the time zone name rather than "Central", with the abbreviations being EST, EDT, AEST, or AEDT.»

Comment: «In domestic contexts the leading "Australian" is often dropped»

Comment: + because the conflicts concern is correct. There are quite a few, if you read the entire list.

Comment: Also, unless your design has an explicitly local or regional scope, you should be avoiding using the abbreviated time zone acronyms (iCalendar calls this a "TZNAME"), and you should use the more explicit "Area/Location" format (iCalendar calls this "TZID").

Be careful here, often your context is global and you won't realize it until later.

Answer (score 1):

Time zones or daylight savings time start/end dates of cities might change (it did occur in the past) but the cities are likely to remain at the same location.

Answer (score 1):

All regions within a timezone don't follow the same rules. For example, Arizona does not observe Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set

Quote from page: Note: Since PHP 5.1.0 (when the date/time functions were rewritten), every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone isn't valid, and/or a E_STRICT message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

"America/Indianapolis" and "America/New_York" are called **TZID** (Timezone Identifier) from the **[tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)** (also called **zoneinfo database** or **IANA time zone database** or **Olson database**).

> The tz database partitions the world into regions where local clocks have all been the same since 1970.

**This means that when specifying a TZID, you can accurately and without ambiguity date any local event in the world occurring since 1 January 1970 ([Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).**

This may seem convenient together with a Unix timestamp. Yet, beware of 32 bits programs as they will report negative values with the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

"EST", "EDT", "CST" and "CDT" are often abbreviations of **[The Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)** and lead to ambiguities as they aren't unique (compare "Central Standard Time", "Central Summer Time", "China Standard Time" and "Cuba Standard Time").

More advantages/disadvantages are given on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info.